# PC not booting from Lubuntu CD image

Tags: boot, system-installation

Nooby Question, I just downloaded Lubuntu 14.04 (32) CD image and burned to a CD disk using Win7
The file is there when viewed in explorer but if I restart the PC with the CD installed the PC wants to start Win 7, no option to start Lubuntu.
The BIOS has the CD drive set as #2 boot option after floppy drive #1. There is no option to boot from USB.
I note the Desktop configuration file has not been copied to the CD nor can I find this file in IE Temp folders. Is this the reason my PC will not boot.
Where can I find a copy of the Desktop configuration file

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the issue may be how you burned to disc.  Did you burn it as a disc image or did you just copy the .iso to the blank disc?

Instructions specific to your version of Windows can be found here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I copied the downloaded file to a CD as a master copy which closed the disk off without copying the desktop config file. I shall try again as directed via your link, tomorrow perhaps. I'm not sure what an "iso" file is, thanks again

Comment: @user278070 it's a type of disk image file that ends with the ".iso" extension.  I don't know if it helps to think of it like an ".exe" file (executable program).  You can either copy the .exe file, or you can double-click it to run (by analogy). So if you copied the iso file, you have another file copy.  But if you **ran** the iso file - it would create a bootable disk from the image file.